# "Use for App Service" parameter when configuring a gateway in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

How can I check **"Use for App Service"** parameter in terraform when configuring a gateway?

This is my current gateway configuration in terraform

```
resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "test" {

  backend_http_settings {
    name                  = "${azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name}-be-htst"
    cookie_based_affinity = "Disabled"
    port                  = 443
    protocol              = "Http"
    request_timeout       = 20
    probe_name            = "${azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name}-be-probe"
  }
}
```

[image: Here I have my azure configuration]

Answer (score 1):

i just went through one of my app gateways, ticking this checkbox changes absolutely nothing in the resource definition >> its safe to ignore it. what you need to do is properly configure your `backendAddressPools`, `backendHttpSettingsCollection` and your `probes` for this to work

that checkbox forces the use of custom probe and "use host name from backend address" which you can "tick" when creating http settings.

some gotchas:

1. backendaddresspools have to have backendaddresses configured:

   "backendAddresses": [
       {
           "fqdn": "webapp.azurewebsites.net"
       }
   ]
2. probe have to have `pickHostNameFromBackendHttpSettings` set to true.

   "pickHostNameFromBackendHttpSettings": true,